# Use dynamic button style through `any ButtonStyle` as parameter

Tags: swiftui

Consider that I have a simple button that I want to apply a button style to:

```
Button(action: action()) {
  Text("Foo")
}
.buttonStyle(buttonConfiguration.style)
```

You can see that there is some kind of configuration object that holds a `ButtonStyle` to achieve a dynamic layout. That leaves the concrete type open during compile time:

```
struct ButtonConfiguration {

  var appearance: Appearance

  var style: any ButtonStyle {
    switch appearance {
      case .normal:
        return NormalStyle()
      case .special:
        return SpecialStyle()
    }
  }
}
```

However, in this code the compiler will complain about the line

```
.buttonStyle(buttonConfiguration.style)
```

> Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'

Which probably stems from the fact, that the ButtonStyle is not known to the compiler as a concrete type but it would expect such. I tried to use

```
var style: some ButtonStyle
```

but that just shifts the problem because now the concrete type returned from `style` must of course be consistent. How can I achieve the dynamism that I intended here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Button styles are not supposed to be dynamic. You should encapsulate the "dynamic thing" you want to do in a single `ButtonStyle`.

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let appearance: Appearance
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switch appearance {
            case .foo:
               // ... build a different view for each appearance...
            case .bar:
               // ... build a different view for each appearance...
        }
    }
}
```

If you are trying to compose other styles together, like:

```
func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    switch appearance {
        case .normal:
           NormalStyle().makeBody(configuration: configuration)
        case .special:
           SpecialStyle().makeBody(configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

The `@State`s in each style would not work. If the styles have their own state, I would suggest inlining everything.

This can then be used like this:

```
.buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle(buttonConfiguration.appearance))
```